# How auth.getCurrentUser() works in firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am not understanding how Auth.getCurrentUser() work? Specifically i want to know

1. Where this current user is stored? Auth.getCurrentUser() gets user from local device or from firebase?
2. If Current User is stored on firebase then how come this is resolved for my application? Because there might be hundreds of user in firebase logged into a particular application?
3. If i make a call to some rest api on server and if i need to authenticate first before making rest call , should i call Auth.getCurrentUser or i should store all information in shared preference and use that everytime?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Where this current user is stored? Auth.getCurrentUser() gets user from local device or from firebase?

After you sign the user in, the `FirebaseUser` is stored in Firebase and cached locally. To force refresh use [`FirebaseUser.reload()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseUser#reload()). You shouldn't need to do this manually, read further.

> If Current User is stored on firebase then how come this is resolved for my application? Because there might be hundreds of user in firebase logged into a particular application?

You may be signed in automatically in [Firebase UI using Smart Lock](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/tree/master/auth#authentication-flow-chart). This can be [adjusted](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/tree/master/auth#smart-lock):

```
startActivityForResult(
    AuthUI.getInstance()
        .createSignInIntentBuilder()
        .setIsSmartLockEnabled(false /* credentials */, true /* hints */)
        .build(),
    RC_SIGN_IN);
```

> If i make a call to some rest api on server and if i need to authenticate first before making rest call , should i call Auth.getCurrentUser or i should store all information in shared preference and use that everytime?

It's already cached locally, use `getCurrentUser`. If the operation fails because the token is expired, use [`FirebaseUser.getIdToken(forceRefresh = true)`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseUser#getIdToken(boolean)) to get a fresh token or fail

> [...] if the current user's account has been disabled, deleted, or its credentials are no longer valid

If that happens, you should treat the user as signed out and re-authenticate them.

Comment: getCurrentUser() get user from local cache? Also how does then my cache update automatically in case user is deleted from other device? @Eugen

Comment: You don't care about the cache. It probably doesn't update automatically. The cache is an implementation detail of Firebase Authentication SDK. You can `getCurrentUser()`, you can [`addAuthStateListener`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseAuth#addAuthStateListener(com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener)), you can deal with `FirebaseAuth*Exception`s on calls that require valid authentication.

Comment: Imagine this: You want to fetch fresh data on app start from your backend. So you need a token. So you get a token. You call you backend which tells you the token is expired. So you try to get a new token with `forceRefresh = true`. It fails with an exception, which tells you the user is signed out or deleted. You update your UI accordingly and ask the user to sign in again.

Comment: As you said "It's already cached locally, use getCurrentUser" so getCurrentUser will return me cached data... and if User is deactivated or deleted from other device then getCurrentUser is returning me deleted user?

Comment: I don't know how the cache inside Firebase Authentication works. We don't need to know. We're expected to handle failures gracefully. The only authority that can delete users will probably be your backend. From the app, your users can only sign out - this affects only the one app on the one device. In case of deletion your backend could notify the user's devices with a custom FCM, which would trigger a local sign out. If your user asks you to delete their data, they may have uninstalled the app so you don't have to deal with it.

Comment: When the deletion happens the user's phone may be off. The app may not be running. So don't get to know that the user in Firebase was deleted immediately. You don't care. You only need the credentials to talk to your backend. And that would fail for a deleted user. Just handle that case gracefully - refresh token, if that doesn't work, delete local data and ask the user to sign in again.

Comment: Again my question is may be that 10 users are using a app, then how firebase return current user differently to all 10 user? does it get device number to identify user?

Comment: Firebase can return "current user" because the person that's using your app authenticates with Firebase in your app using their credentials. They get a different "current user" because they use different email/account. Start with the introductory video on [this page](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth) then read the rest of the documentation.

Comment: so when we call get current user from app, app send some token to firebase and firebase return validated user with that token? is is something like that? because there might be hundred of current user logged in so app must send something from app to get recognise specific user? @Eugen Pechanec

Comment: The user puts their email+password into your app and clicks SIGN IN, Firebase *SDK in your app* sends it to Firebase *cloud*, Firebase cloud returns an *access token* and a *refresh token* for that user. Any call from the Firebase SDK in your app to Firebase cloud goes with that access token (`getCurrentUser`, work with database, work with storage...), so Firebase knows who's asking (the user). If access token expires, refresh token is used to get a fresh access token. If refresh token expires as well, the user needs to sign in again.

Comment: Have you tried this in the latest firebase_auth version